# Write something in HTML depending on the value of JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

We are trying to write different things in our table depending on which value the user gives a specific function:

```
function selected(val){
    if (val == "541"){
        document.getElementById("first").InnerHTML = "541";

        }
}
```

The table:

```
<div class="table">
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
    Teams
    </td>
    <td id = "first">
    </td>
    <td>
    544
    </td>
    <td>
    547
    </td>
    <td>
    550
    </td>
    <td>
    602
    </td>
    <td>
    SLASKEN
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
function selected(val){
if (val == "541"){
    document.getElementById("first").innerHTML = "541";

    }
}
```

instead. (notice the **lowercase** `i`)

Comment: @e.klara.k You are welcome! No worries, typos happen, especially in the beginning. Try to keep calm when encountering JS errors, and remember, the console comes in handy: Developer Tools (Chrome) - Ctrl+Shift+I;  F12 (Internet Explorer), etc, most major browsers have something like that